# Ionic 4, ion-slides vertical scrolling not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, ion-slides

I have a component inside of ion-slide and its is the scroll not working

here is my code :

{{tab}}

```
<ion-slide style="height:100%">
  <main-search></main-search>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>

    <div style="height:100%">Page 2 </div>

</ion-slide>
```

Comment: Could you please go into more detail, how is it not working, what are you expecting, what is happening?

Comment: @PLASMAchicken the main-search component contain a list of element that not scrolling vertical

Comment: @JVManageProj now check my answer

Answer (score 10):

Please try this:

```
.swiper-slide {
    overflow-y: scroll;    
    display: block;    
}
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-scroll-within-ionic-slide-not-working/47099/7

Comment: why isn´t this working for me? I despair.

Comment: Nevermind. I set scrollY="false" in ion-content 

Answer (score 4):

Please try following code:

**.html**

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts"
                pager="true">
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title1</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title2</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title3</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title4</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title5</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title45</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title46</h2>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-slide>

      <ion-slide>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title1</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title2</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title3</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title4</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title5</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title45</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title46</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title1</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title2</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title3</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title4</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title5</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title45</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Some title46</h2>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

**.ts**

```
  slideOpts = {
      initialSlide: 0,
      speed: 500
  };
```

**.scss**

For vertical scrolling

```
ion-slides{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

For horizontal scrolling

```
ion-slides{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```